# Web Audio Api biquadFilter in Android needs extra configuration?

Tags: android, web-audio-api

[Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api) says the Web audio API works in Chrome for Android, and [here](http://www.doboism.com/projects/webaudio-compatibility/) I have tested CM Browser, Chrome and CyanogenMod default Android 5.1.1 browsers, and all pass the tests (specially the biquadNode one).

But When I open [this codepen](http://codepen.io/andremichelle/pen/RNwamZ) with an eq (biquadNode), I can hear the music but not the eq working.

Does biquadNode works in android? any special implementation is needed?

*Code pen required to post

```
    var context = new AudioContext();
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('player');
var sourceNode = context.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement);

// EQ Properties
//
var gainDb = -40.0;
var bandSplit = [360,3600];

var hBand = context.createBiquadFilter();
hBand.type = "lowshelf";
hBand.frequency.value = bandSplit[0];
hBand.gain.value = gainDb;

var hInvert = context.createGain();
hInvert.gain.value = -1.0;

var mBand = context.createGain();

var lBand = context.createBiquadFilter();
lBand.type = "highshelf";
lBand.frequency.value = bandSplit[1];
lBand.gain.value = gainDb;

var lInvert = context.createGain();
lInvert.gain.value = -1.0;

sourceNode.connect(lBand);
sourceNode.connect(mBand);
sourceNode.connect(hBand);

hBand.connect(hInvert);
lBand.connect(lInvert);

hInvert.connect(mBand);
lInvert.connect(mBand);

var lGain = context.createGain();
var mGain = context.createGain();
var hGain = context.createGain();

lBand.connect(lGain);
mBand.connect(mGain);
hBand.connect(hGain);

var sum = context.createGain();
lGain.connect(sum);
mGain.connect(sum);
hGain.connect(sum);
sum.connect(context.destination);

// Input
//
function changeGain(string,type)
{
  var value = parseFloat(string) / 100.0;

  switch(type)
  {
    case 'lowGain': lGain.gain.value = value; break;
    case 'midGain': mGain.gain.value = value; break;
    case 'highGain': hGain.gain.value = value; break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createMediaElementSource` in Chrome on Android doesn't work in general. But if you have a recent build of Chrome (49 and later?), you can go to `chrome://flags` and enable the unified media pipeline option.  That will make `createMediaElementSource` work like on desktop.

Comment: Then I need to tell my website visitors to enable this option ` chrome://flags/#enable-unified-media-pipeline`

Comment: Yes.  If they're using Chrome 49 and later.  I assume that someday this will become the default, but I don't know.